# Stop Words removal from TextView

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a `TextView` which contains a processed text, so that it will be in lower case and doesn't have punctuations. 
Now I want to remove the stop words (these stop words are in my language which I already define). After that, I want to send the result to another `TextView`.

This my code

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (v.getId() == R.id.button6) {
        Intent i2 = new Intent(this, PreposisiRemoval.class);

        String test = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7)).getText()
            .toString();
        String[] preposisi = { "akibat", "atas", "bagai", "bagi", "berkat",
            "dalam", "dari", "demi", "dengan", "di", "hingga",
            "karena", "ke", "kecuali", "lewat", "oleh", "pada",
            "sampai", "sejak", "seperti", "tanpa", "tentang", "untuk" };

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        Scanner fip1 = new Scanner(test);
        while (fip1.hasNext()) {
            int flag = 1;
            String s1 = fip1.next();
            for (int i = 0; i < preposisi.length; i++) {
                if (s1.equals(preposisi[i])) {
                    flag = 0;
                }
                if (flag != 0) {
                    System.out.println(s1);
                    result.append(s1);
                }
            i2.putExtra("result2", result.toString());
            startActivity(i2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After I pressed `button6`, I did not get any results.
Where is the part of my coding that is wrong?

This code is in another `Activity` which will receive the processed text.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_preposisi_removal);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String result = intent.getStringExtra("result2");

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
    tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    tv.setText(result);
    tv.setTextSize(12);
}
```

Comment: please use substring and remove that word from that string

Answer (score 1):

To prepare the text for `result2` you can try the following-

```
String STOP_WORD = "."; // define your stop word here.

String result2= result.replace(STOP_WORD ,"");
```

Then pass the text and set it on your second `TextView`.